# Avoid reload/redraw all components when swapping TabPages

Tags: c#, winforms, performance

I have multiple TabPages on a TabControl. Some of these TabPages contain up to 100 Panels in a FlowLayoutPanel. Each of these Panels also contain a bunch of different controls...

The issue is simple: when I swap between TabPages, the one containing lots of controls take ages (1-2 seconds) to load.
I would like them not to lose "focus", to keep the components in memory or something when left for another tab, so that they don't have to reload everything when we come back on it.

Is it even possible? Or is it the drawing itself that take all this time? I do not do operations when changing tabs. Just displaying them.

Clarification edits:

- Hum, maybe I was not clear enough. The problem is not how the stuff is drawn when being loaded. I have fixed this issue my own way (working with selected tab events). My problem is the time taken by the page to actually load. When I enter the TabPage containing lots of controls (in FlowLayoutPanel), it will load for about 1-2 sec THEN be displayed. I would like that to be almost instant, all controls being already available or something. But maybe it is not possible? Maybe it is the time taken to draw all those controls that is long?
- What's weird is that it takes less time to actually generate all those panels (100 in less than 0.5) for the first time, than to redisplay them when leaving/entering the page after.
- The displaying is also instant when coming from Minimized state (the form itself). I would like that to be the same when changing form state than swapping between tabs.

Comment: Post a complete, short, sample code that can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue with `FlowLayoutPanel` when having many controls inside. It tries to layout all of the controls and each time control is positioned part of the screen is redrawn.

To reduce this, try to enable double buffering on your form or `FlowLayoutPanel` control. This allows to do all rendering in memory first and swap buffers once when it is done.

Add this code:

```
public static void SetDoubleBuffered(System.Windows.Forms.Control c)
{
   //Taxes: Remote Desktop Connection and painting
   //http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/01/03/508694.aspx
   if (System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession)
      return;

   System.Reflection.PropertyInfo aProp = 
         typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Control).GetProperty(
               "DoubleBuffered", 
               System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
               System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

   aProp.SetValue(c, true, null); 
}
```

Then just call this on your form or control.

```
SetDoubleBuffered(mainForm);

SetDoubleBuffered(myFlowPanel);
```

Comment: Because DoubleBuffered is protected. This method is generic and will work for every control. I would not like to inherit all the existing controls just to turn Double Buffering on.

Comment: Sorry for split comment, but could not edit existing one because of timeout. This method would usually be called few times, so you don't have to worry about performance issues. I am giving shortest solution to the problem to illustrate solution, not exact code that can copy-pasted in real project. It is up to OP to implement it properly in current project.

Comment: Hum, maybe I was not clear enough. The problem is not how the stuff is drawn when being loaded. I have fixed this issue my own way (working with selected tab events). My problem is the time taken by the page to actually load. When I enter the TabPage containing lots of controls (in FlowLayoutPanel), it will load for about 1-2 sec THEN be displayed. I would like that to be almost instant, all controls being already available or something. But maybe it is not possible? Maybe it is the time taken to draw all those controls that is long?

Comment: What's weird is that it takes less time to actually generate all those panels (100 in less than 0.5) for the first time, than to redisplay them when leaving/entering the page after.